# google-spreadsheet.js (npm) read only access to cell not working with API KEY - need OAuth?

Tags: node.js, authentication, discord.js, google-sheets-api

From a **node.js** application (a discord bot)
I try to acess to a **public googlesheet** using the npm package [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet)

I followed each step carefully, but I **would like to use only the API key** authentification method instead of a more risky **Oauth** identification

*(my discord bot is public, on heroku and I don't want to mess around with too much sensitive information even though i use environment variables)*

On the documentation of **google-spreadsheet.js** it mentions that :

```js
// OR use API key -- only for read-only access to public sheets
doc.useApiKey('YOUR-API-KEY');
```

I sucessfully could **connect to the 
[spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bny-ZsCG_oUuS0nTbR-7tBBZu47_ncS9qGYaMpuprWU/edit#gid=0)** 
and **read the title of it** and **get the titles of each sheet** but when I call 
`await sheet.loadCells();` 
it gives me the following error

```
Google API error - [401] 
Request is missing required authentication credential.
Expected OAuth 2 access token, 
login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

What would be the right way or **READING ONLY** cells, if possible using only the API KEY authentification ?

here is my full code :

```js
  const sheetId = "1Bny-ZsCG_oUuS0nTbR-7tBBZu47_ncS9qGYaMpuprWU"

  var loaded = {}

  if (message) {
    message.reply("je me connecte à Google Sheets...")
  }

  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetId);

  doc.useApiKey(process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY);

  await doc.loadInfo();
  loaded.docTitle = doc.title;
  loaded.sheets = {};

  if (message) {
    message.reply("...connection réussie, je récupère les infos...")
  }

  // get the spreadsheets
  for (let s = 0; s < doc.sheetCount; ++s ) {
    const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[s];
    loaded.sheets[sheet.title] = {sheetReference:sheet};

    loaded.sheets[sheet.title].data = []

    await sheet.loadCells(); // <---------it seems to block here

    for (let row= 0; row < sheet.rowCount; ++row) {
      loaded.sheets[sheet.title].data.push([])

      for (let col = 0; col < sheet.columnCount; ++col) {
        let cell = sheet.getCell(row, col).value;
        loaded.sheets[sheet.title].data[row].push(cell)
      }
    }
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: Is your application authorized for the scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly 
 ??

Have a read at [this for authorization protocols](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing) for sheets-api

Comment: You might also find the 10 mins this [Sheets-API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) takes worth your while

Comment: yes, as of @Tanaike 's answer, I realized I was using the wrong library. But with Oauth2 , google-spreadsheet.js works well and it's simple to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values from Google Spreadsheet using the API key.
- The Google Spreadsheet is publicly shared.
- You want to achieve this using [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet).

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue and workaround:

When I saw [the source script](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet) of google-spreadsheet, it seems that `sheet.loadCells()` requests with the POST method using the API key. [Ref](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/blob/bd8eba66a405c2a01a47089680c0019ec07e9fa6/lib/GoogleSpreadsheet.js#L292) Unfortunately, the API key cannot use the POST method. So such error occurred. I think that the reason of this issue is due to this. For example, when the access token from OAuth2 and service account is used, I could confirm that `sheet.loadCells()` worked. From this situation, this might be a bug or the specification of the library.

Fortunately, the values can be retrieved from the publicly shared Google Spreadsheet with the API key. So as one of several workarounds, in this answer, [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) is used as a simple method. This is the official library.

### Sample script:

At first, please install googleapis. And please set the variables of `spreadsheetId` and `APIKey`.

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const spreadsheetId = "1Bny-ZsCG_oUuS0nTbR-7tBBZu47_ncS9qGYaMpuprWU"; // This is from your script.
const APIKey = "### your API key ###";

const sheets = google.sheets({version: "v4", auth: APIKey});
sheets.spreadsheets.get({ spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId }, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet(
    {
      spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
      ranges: res.data.sheets.map(e => e.properties.title)
    },
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));
    }
  );
});
```

- When you run the script, the all values from all sheets in the publicly shared Spreadsheet are retrieved.
- In above sample script, there are 2 methods of spreadsheets.get and spreadsheets.values.batchGet were used.

### References:

- [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)
- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: you sure understood my question ! thank you, I only had a quick search and did not find the **official googleapis** library.

Comment: for now I made it work finally using the Oauth2 authentication, but I will sure give a try to your solution, since I prefer having only the API KEY to store in config variables. Thank you !

Comment: @Gui3 the ***official googleapis client*** is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs#further_reading) on the [first link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#google-apis-nodejs-client). Hope it helps.

Comment: @Gui3 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Aerials Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Author of [google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet) here.

I've just released an update that should fix this problem. It was a very subtle difference in google's API docs that I missed. The `loadCells` method now will default to the regular [get endpoint](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) if using an API key only. The interface for loadCells is the same, but will only support A1 ranges in this mode.

Cheers!